# NewsStand View implementation

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I want to implement newsstand like split. I have developed a navigation based app where i want split which comes after tapping a [newsstand](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#newsstand) application. i tried doing this by taking two image views and then add my root view in upper imageView and keep that view up all the views. but then i couldn't able to access the root view. and if i add images over the root view but then the bottom image also moving with root view instead of opposite direction.

is there any way to active split like newsStand.